# SP2013 Failed to create the configuration database

Tags: 2013, error, installation, sql

When installing SP2013 I got this error:

> Failed to create the configuration database
>
> An exception of type Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPException was thrown.
>   Additional exception information: The language is not supported on the
>   server.

I tried to doing this:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2002277
I don't have a directory 12, so I did it in 14 and 15 instead.

This was suggested on some other forums as well.
Still didn't fix my problem.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What language are you using on the server itself and on the SharePoint installation? Also, is your SQL server local or on a separate machine?

Comment: 12 is for SP 2007 that is why you do not have this directory. 14 is for 2010 and 15 for 2013. SP 2013 creates both 14 and 15 directory for backwards compatibility with SP2010 solutions.

Comment: Also have you installed any version of SharePoint on this server before and subsequently uninstalled it?

Comment: The language on the server i am using is English. The SQL server is local. Yes the server used to run SharePoint Foundations, which I unistalled through control panel

Comment: Please check your OS and SQL versions: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(v=office.15).aspx#section4

Comment: I am running Windows server 2012 R2 and SQL server 2012. I am trying to reinstall SQL server and sharepoint to see if that helps..

Comment: When you uninstall SharePoint make sure you get rid of any language packs that may have been installed with it. I've seen those cause this kind of problem before, though that doesn't mean it's definitely the cause this time.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling SharePoint, all SharePoint language packages, and SQL server. Then reinstalling it all solved this issue.

I did also run into Error 503: Service Unavailable, when opening central administrator for the first time. That problem was solved as mentioned [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAF1q0GwKmM)